# GridView background style in android

Tags: android, styles, android-gridview, android-background

I want to create a similar layout like the image. `ListView` is on left side and its respective `GridView` is shown on right. I have to create similar layout to this but I am unable to create a GridView background similar to the image. Can anyone help me out to create a similar design of GridView background which points to its respective ListView position.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is a nasty solution, but you could include the arrow in your ListView's items' background. In short:

1. use a selector to change the item's background depending on its state.
2. Specify a background for the selected state, which includes the arrow.
3. Make sure your adapter processes the selected state correctly - i.e. once you press an item, mark its content (not only the view) as selected and in the adapter's `getView` method get the selected state from the content and set it to the view.

It is not the perfect solution, but is pretty easy and should do.